# React Native TextInput autofill validation

Tags: react-native, forms

I'm using the TextInput core component of react native for getting user email. The onChangeText stores the text in local state. The validation function is subscribed to the textInput's onBlur prop and validates the email in the state variable.

```
<TextInput
    label="Email"
    keyboardType="email-address"
    value={email}
    onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text.trim())}
    onBlur={() => validateEmail()}
    onFocus={() => setErrEmail(undefined)}
/>
```

The problem is running the validation with autofill. If the user selects the autofill option then there is a slight delay in the text updating in state but the validation runs immediately.

This results in the validation failing. After the slight delay the input field even shows the autofill value, which is worse, because usually that value should have been validated.

How can I resolve the inconsistency between the validation running immediately with empty value but the state getting updated with a delay?

I have tried using setTimeout for the validation but it is resulting in app crashes.

Is there a way to resolve this using the native TextInput or will I have to look at another library to handle form validations with autofill?

Comment: Could you give some code ? It could be more explicite